Flowable 7.1.0 test can't find flowable.cfg.xml when test is run
I've built a flowable 7.1.0 Groovy Spring Boot Gradle project, which works when I run manually. However I copied my test process into test/resources/processes, built a simple test, and annotated my Junit 5 test with @FlowableTest
@FlowableTest
//@SpringBootTest
class ProcessTest {

    private ProcessEngine processEngine
    private RuntimeService runtimeService
    private TaskService taskService

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
        this.processEngine = processEngine
        this.runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService()
        this.taskService = processEngine.getTaskService()
    }

    @Test
    @Deployment (resources = [ "processes/one-task-process-test.bpmn20.xml" ])
    void testOneTaskProcess() {
        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("oneTaskProcessTest")

        Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().singleResult()

        assertEquals("my task", task.getName())

        taskService.complete(task.getId())
        assertEquals(0, runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().count())
    }
}

My build.gradle dependencies are
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '3.4.0'
    implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-spring-boot-starter-process', version: '7.1.0'
    implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-spring-boot-starter-rest-api', version: '7.0.0.M1'
    //implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-idm-spring', version: '7.1.0'
    //include groovy script engine for groovy script tasks
    implementation group: 'org.apache.groovy', name: 'groovy-jsr223', version: '4.0.24'

 
    implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.3.232'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '3.4.0'
    //for actuator bean
    //implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '6.4.1'
    //implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '6.4.1'
    
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy:4.0.14'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '3.4.0'


    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.3.232'

}

but when you run the test I get this error
...
class path resource [flowable.cfg.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [flowable.cfg.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:215)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:319)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.cfg.BeansConfigurationHelper.parseEngineConfiguration(BeansConfigurationHelper.java:38)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.cfg.BeansConfigurationHelper.parseEngineConfigurationFromResource(BeansConfigurationHelper.java:62)
    at org.flowable.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResource(ProcessEngineConfiguration.java:176)
    at org.flowable.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResource(ProcessEngineConfiguration.java:172)
    at org.flowable.engine.impl.test.TestHelper.getProcessEngine(TestHelper.java:254)
    at org.flowable.engine.test.FlowableExtension.createProcessEngine(FlowableExtension.java:198)
    at org.flowable.engine.test.FlowableExtension.lambda$getTestHelper$4(FlowableExtension.java:194)
    ...

Where have I gone wrong? Why do I need a flowable.cfg.xml and where would that go?

I was expecting the flowable test framework to set up all this through its annotations.
however did some digging about and found this page entry https://www.flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch03-Configuration
So in my test/resources folder I created a flowable.cfg.xml file and (for h2 in memory testing) a file that has this in it
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.flowable.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:flowable;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
        <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
        <property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />

        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />

        <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="false" />

    </bean>

</beans>

When you then try and re-run the tests it appears to run without the errors.  Need to post a message to the Flowable project says that by default your tests won't work even when annotated with @FlowableTest
